# Status Code: 500 Exception: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.InvalidObjectIdException: Invalid id : Process leaked file descriptors. See htt Stacktrace

Tags: github, jenkins

I am trying to build an example "game-of-life" by github. I was able to clone the repository using the command line in windows.
When I give the URL of repository in Jenkins, I get follow error message:

```
Status Code: 500
Exception: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.InvalidObjectIdException: Invalid id : Process leaked file descriptors. See htt
Stacktrace:

javax.servlet.ServletException: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.InvalidObjectIdException: Invalid id : Process leaked file descriptors. See htt
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:719)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:241)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:770)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:583)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:214)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:45)
    at winstone.ServletConfiguration.execute(ServletConfiguration.java:248)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:333)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:376)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:95)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:87)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:50)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at winstone.FilterConfiguration.execute(FilterConfiguration.java:194)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.doFilter(RequestDispatcher.java:366)
    at winstone.RequestDispatcher.forward(RequestDispatcher.java:331)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.processRequest(RequestHandlerThread.java:227)
    at winstone.RequestHandlerThread.run(RequestHandlerThread.java:150)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.eclipse.jgit.errors.InvalidObjectIdException: Invalid id : Process leaked file descriptors. See htt
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId.fromHexString(ObjectId.java:245)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.ObjectId.fromString(ObjectId.java:233)
    at org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.getHeadRev(CliGitAPIImpl.java:1062)
    at hudson.plugins.git.UserRemoteConfig$DescriptorImpl.doCheckUrl(UserRemoteConfig.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor369.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:288)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:151)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:90)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:677)
    ... 43 more
```

What does that mean? Should I configure something in eclipse (I am not using eclipse for this application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved. I don't know the exact reason. I just configured ssh keys on my system, which is behind a proxy server. That may be the reason for this error.